# How to store and retrieve value of button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm making a checkin app for my soccer team. I think I got the buttons programmed properly but I'm having problems storing the value and retrieving the value from mySQL database. Can someone please tell me what piece of code I'm missing? thanks in advance.

```
<style>
    .height {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .height2 {
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fc {
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    body {
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 4em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .btn-xl {
        padding: 15px 24px;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 1.4;
        border-radius: 8px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($, window, document) {
        $(function() {
            // bind to the click event of the checkin button
            $('.btn-player-checkin').on('click', function() {
                // if the button has the success class - assume the user is checked in
                var isCheckedIn = $(this).hasClass('btn-success');
                // get the player id from the data attribute
                var playerId = $(this).data('player-id');


                // call the send function
                // sendDataToServer(!isCheckedIn, playerId, $(this)); // send the status we want the player to save (ie. opposite of current);

                // if you would like to test the success function without the ajax call, comment out above and uncomment below
                if (!isCheckedIn) { // trying to check out
                    $(this).text('IN');
                } else { // checking in
                    $(this).text('OUT');
                }
                // cycle classes
                $(this).toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');

            });

            function sendDataToServer(newStatus, playerId, button) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://labombafootball.com/checkin', // replace this with the url of the server end point
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        playerId: playerId,
                        status: newStatus
                    } // send this data, on the server you could also record the timestamp of when this occurred
                }).done(function() { // if we successfully complete the post
                    if (newStatus) { // checking in
                        button.text('OUT');
                    } else { // trying to check out
                        button.text('IN');
                    }
                    // cycle classes
                    button.toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');
                }).fail(function() {
                    // do something if the post fails
                });
            }
        });
    }(window.jQuery, window, document));
</script>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 height"><img class="fc" src="images/la-bomba-fc-sm.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#2 STEVE B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="2">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#1 INDER JHOOTY</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="1">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#21 CHRIS NAKATSU</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="21">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#88 NICK MARSHALL</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="88">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#99 TONY YUN</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="99">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#6 DANIELE BORRELLI</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="6">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#11 NITESH SHETTY</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="11">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#45 UDAYA MADANAYAKE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="45">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#9 ADRIAN PARTYKA</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="9">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#5 PATRICK REGAN</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="5">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#13 RAMEZ ALAM</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="13">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#8 FAIZAN ALAM</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="8">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#33 DAVID CLEBAN</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="33">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#14 VICTOR JIMENEZ</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="14">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#7 HARRY SANDHU</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="7">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#77 JOHN PINEDA</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="77">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#44 DEVON CARNEY</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="44">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 height2">#17 JUSTIN CONSTANTINEAU</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xl btn-player-checkin" data-player-id="17">OUT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the actual question about? do you get error? is player id not correct? If so try $(this).attr('player-id'); instead of $(this).data('player-id')

Comment: you can see the site live at http://www.labombafootball.com , there's no error message but I don't think I've properly programmed my buttons to store the value and link to mySql database.

Comment: `I don't think I've` - so something is incorrect? does the ajax request go ahead? is there a problem, maybe, with the server side code you haven't shown?

Comment: `// sendDataToServer( ...` that's a comment, so it doesn't actually call `sendDataToServer` function - perhaps that's the problem

Comment: yeah that's where I struggle I'm not sure how to do the server side programming.

Comment: so what have you managed to do server side so far (pre-emptive warning: don't put any code you've done so far in a comment)

Comment: well so far I just made an sql table with playerId and newStatus

Comment: What is your endpoint? Is it built to consume the 'data' you are passing it? Or do do you plan on trying to insert directly into your DB?

If so, you need to use a server side language like node.js or php. 
You will need the 'POST" from the ajax call to process it before it makes it to the DB. When i say process I mean evaluating the POST data and writing a dynamic* SQL insert statement. You are missing half the puzzle here

Comment: is there a way to do that with phpMyAdmin?